# Bootstrap 3 equal height thumbnails (like equal height cards in bootstrap 4)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a row of thumbnails like this:

[image]

I want them to be equal height though. This is my code:

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>HOTKEY + COMBO</h3>
                <p>Hotkey description goes here. Category only shown in explore.</p>
                <p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-tooltip="Change Hotkey">
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>HOTKEY + COMBO</h3>
                <p>short desc</p>
                <p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-tooltip="Change Hotkey">
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hotkey-add">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <p></p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible? Like we see in bootstrap4 here is equal height cards:

http://www.codeply.com/render/KrUO8QpyXP#

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that bootstrap 4, like you show in the example, is using to get the same height, `display: table` for the container div and `display: table-cell` for the inner ones.

Other solution can be using `<table>` instead `<div>`, using `flex` property...
Checkout this [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Comment: Thank you @anfuca I will experiment wit this!

Answer (score 12):

I know I'm a little late on this, but I think the best way is **flexbox**. Here's how it would work in Bootstrap 3:

```
.row.display-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.thumbnail {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Just add `display-flex` to the containing `row`. Also, the upcoming Bootstrap 4 has flexbox as the default so this extra CSS won't be necessary in the future.

[Thumbnails with flexbox](http://www.codeply.com/go/cWHZbq0wpt)

You can also do more with the [position of child elements](http://www.codeply.com/go/cWHZbq0wpt).

---

Also see,
[make Bootstrap columns all the same height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22892773/171456)

Comment: Thanks Zim for this. I was avoiding flex box because the browser support for this feature is weak isn't it?